# add items in array dynamically with button click

Tags: jquery, html

i have a textbox and a button so basically when i click on the button whatever is written on the text box should be added to an array

```
       <input id"item" type="text">
      <input id"clickme" type="submit">
        $('#send-btn').click(function() { 
     var = item    $("#item").val()
  var itemofarrays[] ???
//add this items to an and then  display them
alert(itemofarrays)
    });
```

iam unable to add to an array when i type something in the input box please help

Comment: Which element you want to show when click submit?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something you are looking for

```
$('#send-btn').click(function() { 
    var item =  $("#item").val();
    //add this items to an and then  display them
    itemofarrays.push(item);
    $('#showItem').val(itemofarrays.join(','));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this code but it should be something like:

```
var itemofarrays = [];
$('#send-btn').click(function() { 
   var item;  
   item = $("#item").val();
   //add this items to an and then  display them
   itemofarrays.push(item);
   alert(itemofarrays);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>My First JavaScript</h2>
    <input id="item" type="text">
    <input id="send-btn" type="submit">
    <script>
        var itemofarrays=[];
        $('#send-btn').click(function() { 
            var item =   $("#item").val();
            itemofarrays.push(item);
            //add this items to an and then  display them
            alert(itemofarrays);
       });
    </script>
</body>
</html> 
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of split() method which will split entered text and it will be array which can be assigned to itemofarrays

Few syntax errors that needs to be fixed in your code,

1.Use same id for click event i.e clickme instead of send-btn
2.**"="** is missing for id values , **id"item"** to **id = "item"** and **id"clickme"** to **id ="clickme"**

```js
  var itemofarrays=[]

$('#clickme').on('click',function() { 
     var item =  $("#item").val()
     itemofarrays = item.split('')
console.log(itemofarrays)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="item" type="text">
      <input id="clickme" type="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Try jQuery Online</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            var itemofarrays = [];

           $('#clickme').click(function() { 

             itemofarrays.push($("#item").val());
             $("#result").val(itemofarrays);
             $("#item").val('')
            });
        });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="item" type="text"/>
        <input id="clickme" type="submit"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input id="result" type="text" readonly="true"/>
    </body>
</html>
```